# Defect - The links "add a comment" do not work

Tags: support, bug, comments

There is an annoying defect in the site https://musicfans.stackexchange.com

I am on the site https://musicfans.stackexchange.com on an iPhone on iOS 9.0.2.

The links "add a comment" do not work.

I think this is a regression.

Can someone correct that defect please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You are using an [unsupported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/295232). iOS 9 is five years old now, and its Safari browser doesn't support some of the JavaScript that link is using (at least, that's my assumption). I'm sorry, but it's unlikely the development team will fix that bug. It's hard keeping a site working on so many different browsers, that energy is better spent elsewhere.